# How to install without loosing any data in my HDD

Tags: linux-mint, windows, system-installation

I want to change my OS to Linux Mint in my Windows 7 laptop without loosing any of the files in my hard disk.

Comment: You start with making a backup, once you have that you can proceed any way you want.

Answer (score 2):

The simple option is using backup. You should have backup anyway - one day you will regret if you don't.

If you don't, but you have separate primary partition (like `D:` or something) with files stored on it, you might keep it, then mount it and use it (and maybe after installation - change filesystem, but that requires moving files).

However, backup is crucial. If something goes wrong during installation (e.g. you accidentally format the `D:` partition), your data is lost.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow any step-by-step Linux installation guide, e.g., [Guide To Install Linux Mint Alongside Windows](https://itsfoss.com/guide-install-linux-mint-16-dual-boot-windows/). Please remember to take **backup** of your hard disk before you do anything.

In general, during the installation process you would be asked whether you want to use the entire HDD or do something else. If you want to have dual boot, you must **not** use the entire HDD. Rather, create **separate partitions** for Linux. See step # 4 in the installation guide linked above for details. However, if you do not want to retain your Windows, you can select the "Erase disk" option in step # 4.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either:

- Backup the files, that is copy them somewhere. And then back after you have installed Mint.

or

- Organise space on the hard drive by resizing the Windows partition(s), if needed, before or during Mint installation. The installer should be equipped with a partitioning tool, which will be presented to you during the installation process. In it, again - *if needed* - as you may already have the space for Mint, you need to squeeze as much space as you need and is possible form the present partitions, delete what can be deleted, and install Mint in the freed space. Then after Mint has been installed, you will see the old Windows partition, and be able to access the files there. (Backup is not necessary, but *advisable* with this scenario for the possibility of data loss in case something goes wrong.)

Comment: I have partitioned my hardisk into two one for storing Os files and other for my personal files.But after installation I can open only OS Stored partition.When I open the other it says like"disk cant be mounted".I tried to delete that partition and recreate it but I cant do that it is showing error

Comment: Post this with details as another question.